# http headers necessary ensure cloudfront distributed files don't get browser cached

Tags: http, http-headers, amazon-cloudfront

I have a Rails-generated JS file that I want to distribute via CloudFront (using my Rails app on EC2 as the origin server). Does anyone know which headers I should use in the response for my JS file to ensure that the end user's browser does not cache the JS file?

I know CloudFront does not respect any expires headers that are less than 1 hour... but the docs say those headers are still passed on to the client:
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/

Am I safe using the following?

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
```

Comment: It seems like those headers make it so that CloudFront doesn't even cache the content... every request seems to be hitting my origin server.

Comment: Why are you using CloudFront for a file that shouldn't be cached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm so it turns out I don't really want to be doing that at all. CloudFront respects `no-cache` headers so this will, in fact, not cache the JS file on CloudFront for an hour. It doesn't really make sense to use CloudFront for this... more information can be found on my AWS Forums [post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=68477&tstart=0).

Answer (score 1):

Apparently CF no longer respects `no-cache` header any more. I tried a few combinations of `Cache-Control`, `Pragma`, and `Expires` headers but CF always returns `X-Cache:Hit from cloudfront` after the first access. It does however pass these headers on to the client as-is.